# Measure S21 between 2 antennas at certain frequency using a Spectrum Analyzer

Tags: antenna, spectrum-analyzer, propagation

RX antenna is connected to the Spectrum Analyzer whose reading is regarded as P_RX. TX antenna is connected to a transceiver module that is set to work at the target frequency and emit certain power (P_TX). 
Question: Can I deduct S21 from P_TX-P_RX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can deduce an S21 (forward gain) from that by dividing P_RX / P_TX but I think that that number **would not mean very much**.

Move the RX and TX further apart: that S21 will change

Move the TX antenna (assuming non-isotropic radiation pattern): that S21 will change

Move the RX antenna (assuming non-isotropic radiation pattern): that S21 will change

Stand in between RX and TX: that S21 will change

Place something conductive between RX and TX: that S21 will change

So I do not see how the S21 you'd get would **mean** anything at all. It would be the S21 under those circumstances. I fail to see how that number can be useful in any way.

Comment: What I am trying to get is how S21 changes when I move TX away. The TX is moving inside a certain medium. Hopefully, I can get a path loss model out of such setup.

Comment: OK, if the medium is the only thing you change then indeed the S21 results could mean something. I was thinking that you were interested in the absolute value but you're not, you're interested in the relative values.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a measurement of scalar S21 (power gain only) using Spectrum analyzer on the medium (antenna + free space + conductor).

You won't have good accuracy on the phase information compared to VNA.

People do use SA + SG for S21 measurements especially if they want to get the channel matrix over a long distance.

In that case, to ensure a good phase accuracy, one has to use a GPS clock for synchronization, over the two remote Tx and Rx.